# Interface Model Binding - MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an object derived from interface. I want to use display template and editor template.Display template works very well. But editor template does not work very well.It does not understand it says "can not create instance of an interface". 
I have a custom model binder. But it is really dummy.

```
      protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext,ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType)
    {        
        if (modelType.Equals(typeof(IExample)))
        {
            Type instantiationType = typeof(ExampleType1);
            var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(instantiationType);
            bindingContext.ModelMetadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(null, instantiationType);
            bindingContext.ModelMetadata.Model = obj;
            return obj;
        }

        return base.CreateModel(controllerContext, bindingContext, modelType);
    }
```

How can I do it for every class derived from IExample? Any ideas?

---

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    { 
        MyModel model = new MyModel();

        model.inter = new ExampleType1();

        model.inter.number = 50;

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]        
    public ActionResult Index(MyModel model)
    {
           //*-*-* I want to get it here.

         return View();
     }
```

---

```
public class MyModel
{

   public IExample inter { get; set; }

}


public interface IExample
{
    int number { get; set; }
}

public class ExampleType1 : IExample
{
    public int number { get; set; }
    public string tip1 { get; set; }
}
public class ExampleType2 : IExample
{
    public int number { get; set; }
    public string tip2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "How can I do it for every class derived from IExample? Any ideas?". Also, i think the part in moel binder is wrong. Should be: bindingContext.ModelMetadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(null, modelType);

Comment: I only created instance for ExampleType1.
  Type instantiationType = typeof(ExampleType1); In My index action I said IExample is type of ExampleType1 . But i could say it is ExampleType2.
 I want to create an instance for ExampleType2 as well. But i want to do this dynamic. I can have more classes derived from IExample.

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8276627/how-can-i-build-a-custom-model-binder-which-will-return-different-types-of-model.  But I agree with Botis, that there are probably better approaches.

Answer (score 1):

Without dwelling on reason why you need this ( i think it's a bad design, to have interface in as a parameter for controller methods). I think the simplest solution would be to extend the IExample interface with string property ImplementedType.

```
public interface IExample
{
    string type {get;}
    int number { get; set; }
}
```

Implementation:

```
public class ExampleType1 : IExample
{
    public string type 
    { get { return "ExampleType1"; } }
    public int number { get; set; }
    public string tip1 { get; set; }
}
```

And model binder:

```
var type = (string)bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("type");
if (type == "ExampleType1")
{
    //create new instance of exampletype1. 
}
```

Comment: I tried this. But bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("type") returns null.

Comment: You should try inspecting the messages between client/server (you can use chrome developer tools) and check, if the "type" property is actually send to the server. If not, you probably need to add it to you'r form or whatever place you are actually posting the data to server.

Comment: I added to view the variable 'type'. And then When I submitted , I reached with bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("inter.type"); (inter my propertyname in MyModel).

ValueProviderResult type =  bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("inter.type");
                if (type.AttemptedValue == "ExampleType1"){}

. Maybe I can make unvisible 'type' variable in view . But it is not clean solution.